# Safely join relative URL segments in Python

Tags: python

Without ever knowing anything about how the domain name, what is the best way to join several URL segments into a relative URL?

An example would be something like this:

```
>>> url_relative_join("/", "seg1", "", "seg2/", "seg3")
/seg1/seg2/seg3
```

Looks a lot like `os.path.join`... It there an equivalent library for URLs?

I've looked into `urlparse`, but it seems to work only with absolute URLs.